# Console output on datastore operation

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Is there a way to get a console output whenever the App Engine Datastore is altered/read/queried?

This would help to understand when persistence frameworks like Objectify do really access the datastore and when they use cached values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html) that will give you datastore access in a dsahboard, but you can register hooks yourself the same way appstats is doing it and print the requests to console.

Comment: This is great. Much better than anything I was hoping for. Thank you!